# SQL Server select missing element in series (text-number mix rather than numbers)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to find missing elements - or the next free one for a series:

Sample values:

```
ABK0001X
ABK0002X
ABK0003X
ABK0004X
FRZ0001Q
FRZ0002Q
FRZ0005Q
```

I would like to query for example next "ABK...X" -> should return ABK0005X or next "FRZ...Q" should either return the first missing (FRZ0003Q) or the next free after the highest existing one (FRZ0006Q).

There are some posts dealing with missing numbers - in my case I need to dig the numeric element somehow out of the value

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Are all of the values a three-letter prefix, a four-digit zero-filled one-based integer and a single-letter suffix? Guessing at a pattern, if any, doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

> in my case I need to dig the numeric element somehow out of the value

Here is your starting point. It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(100) = N'FRZ0002Q';
    
;WITH Tally (I)AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I + 1
    FROM Tally
    WHERE I <= (DATALENGTH(@Name) / 2) 
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@Name, T.I, 1), '') AS C
FROM Tally AS T
WHERE TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(@Name, T.I, 1) AS INT) IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output**

```
0002
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    [Nummer]
    , LEFT(Nummer,3) as Pref
    , SUBSTRING(Nummer, 4, 4) as Nr
    , RIGHT(Nummer,1) as Postf
    , CAST(SUBSTRING(Nummer, 4, 4) as int)+1 as NextNr
  FROM [dbo].[Nummerntest]

WHERE LEFT(Nummer,3) = 'ABK'  
ORDER By NextNr desc
```

This brings next free one on top of highest, need to put it back into one result value.

Comment: So the last letter (`Postf`) doesn't matter, you just want to group `'ABK0001X'` together with `'ABK0042A'` since your filter is just `WHERE LEFT(Nummer,3) = 'ABK'`, right? And you don't want to check for missing values, just get the maximum + 1 (`TOP 1`/`ORDER By NextNr desc`) for that three-letter prefix? Seems like an odd answer to the OP's question, but you would know if it works.